# Geometrical shape centroids with vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

a) The diagonals *OB* and *AC* of a parallelogram *OABC* meet at the point *X*. Using vectors show that *X* is the midpoint of both *OB* and *AC*.

b) Let *D* and *E* be the midpoints of *OC* and *BC* in the parallelogram above. Show that *X* is the centroid of the triangle *ADE*.

I got part a) but haven't a clue what to do for part b). Just put in part a) for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b)

Let $\vec{OA}=\vec a,\vec{OC}=\vec c$. Then, we have
$$\vec{OX}=\frac 12\vec{OB}=\frac 12\vec a+\frac 12\vec c,\quad\vec{OD}=\frac 12\vec c,\quad \vec{OE}=\vec{OC}+\vec{CE}=\vec c+\frac 12\vec a$$

Now all you need is to show that
$$\frac 13\left(\vec{OA}+\vec{OD}+\vec{OE}\right)=\vec{OX}.$$

Comment: Thak you, but i'm not sure how to show that completely i only get to converting OB into OA and OC, then im not sure how to convert OC to OD and OE

Comment: @dahaka5: $\frac 13(\vec{OA}+\vec{OD}+\vec{OE})=\frac 13(\vec a+\frac 12\vec c+\vec c+\frac 12\vec a)=\cdots$ Can you continue?

Comment: Ah yeah i get it now, thank you!